# Synchronise 3 Highcharts Trend Views

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, synchronization

I'm looking for some help with syncing 3 line charts similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/v2t171og/

Here is my code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EerNyO

```
(function() {
  var files = ["https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js", "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"],
    loaded = 0;
  if (typeof window["HighchartsEditor"] === "undefined") {
    window.HighchartsEditor = {
      ondone: [cl],
      hasWrapped: false,
      hasLoaded: false
    };
    include(files[0]);
  } else {
    if (window.HighchartsEditor.hasLoaded) {
      cl();
    } else {
      window.HighchartsEditor.ondone.push(cl);
    }
  }

  function isScriptAlreadyIncluded(src) {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
      if (scripts[i].hasAttribute("src")) {
        if ((scripts[i].getAttribute("src") || "").indexOf(src) >= 0 || (scripts[i].getAttribute("src") === "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" && src === "https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js")) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function check() {
    if (loaded === files.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < window.HighchartsEditor.ondone.length; i++) {
        try {
          window.HighchartsEditor.ondone[i]();
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      }
      window.HighchartsEditor.hasLoaded = true;
    }
  }

  function include(script) {
    function next() {
      ++loaded;
      if (loaded < files.length) {
        include(files[loaded]);
      }
      check();
    }
    if (isScriptAlreadyIncluded(script)) {
      return next();
    }
    var sc = document.createElement("script");
    sc.src = script;
    sc.type = "text/javascript";
    sc.onload = function() {
      next();
    };
    document.head.appendChild(sc);
  }

  function each(a, fn) {
    if (typeof a.forEach !== "undefined") {
      a.forEach(fn);
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (fn) {
          fn(a[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var inc = {},
    incl = [];
  each(document.querySelectorAll("script"), function(t) {
    inc[t.src.substr(0, t.src.indexOf("?"))] = 1;
  });

  function cl() {
    if (typeof window["Highcharts"] !== "undefined") {
      var options = {
        "chart": {
          "type": "line",
          "height": 220,
          "polar": false
        },
        "rangeSelector": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "title": {
          "text": ""
        },
        "scrollbar": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "subtitle": {
          "text": ""
        },
        "series": [{
          "name": "RMS",
          "_colorIndex": 0,
          "_symbolIndex": 0,
          "turboThreshold": 0,
          "marker": {}
        }, {
          "name": "Minimum",
          "_colorIndex": 1,
          "_symbolIndex": 1
        }, {
          "name": "Maximum",
          "_colorIndex": 2,
          "_symbolIndex": 2
        }, {
          "name": "Threshold",
          "_colorIndex": 3,
          "_symbolIndex": 3
        }],
        "data": {
          "csv": "\"Movement\";\"RMS\";\"Minimum\";\"Maximum\";\"Threshold\"\n1;12.87;12;15;14\n2;13.16;12;15;14\n3;12.92;12;15;14\n4;13.14;12;15;14\n5;12.88;12;15;14\n6;13.03;12;15;14\n7;12.76;12;15;14\n8;13.04;12;15;14\n9;12.72;12;15;14\n10;13.2;12;15;14",
          "googleSpreadsheetKey": false,
          "googleSpreadsheetWorksheet": false
        },
        "yAxis": [{
          "title": {}
        }],
        "navigator": {
          "adaptToUpdatedData": true,
          "enabled": false
        },
        "pane": {
          "background": []
        },
        "responsive": {
          "rules": []
        },
        "plotOptions": {
          "series": {
            "animation": false
          }
        }
      };
      new Highcharts.StockChart("highcharts-aaf432a9-4966-4429-b3eb-d35fe01e2924", options);
    }
  }
})();
```

I've created the graphs but I can't connect them using the highcharts events or hairlines.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should look at the console, you have a few error there, related with the location of the scripts. Next, you need to change `highlight` method to `onMouseOver`:

```
                    $('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
                        var chart,
                            point,
                            i,
                            event;

                        for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {
                            chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
                            event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart
                            point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point

                            if (point) {
                                point.onMouseOver(e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#onMouseOver

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0gmrf64y/

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was trying to do. One problem though - when I try to download the code from the fiddle it doesn't act the same in my browser.

Comment: You have to add `https:` prefix to jQuery script: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gdyj3fax/1/

Comment: Thank you so much :) I'm hoping you may be able to help to also sync the range selector at the top of the first and the navigator bar at the bottom of the last chart with the others? See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s5xch17m/2

Comment: Hi Yvicci, I think you should open new stackoverflow topic with this question.